# using a filter for a list and narrowing the list by the contents of a column

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, find, google-sheets-formula

I have a filter to get the contents of a column in another spreadsheet and I want to narrow the list by the contents of another column, which is done by

```
=FILTER(MasterList!$A$2:A,(MasterList!$E$2:E = "TL"))
```

But column E may have in the cell the TL value alone or may be combined with other values such as "TL SC AD" of "TL AD" etc in any order and combination. In short, I need to look for CONTAINS "TL"

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need:

```
=FILTER(MasterList!A2:A, REGEXMATCH(MasterList!E2:E, "TL"))
```

[image: 0]

---

for more attributes you can do:

```
=FILTER(MasterList!A2:A, REGEXMATCH(MasterList!E2:E, "TL|XXX|AAA"))
```

and to make it case insensitive do:

```
=FILTER(MasterList!A2:A, REGEXMATCH(UPPER(MasterList!E2:E), "TL|XXX"))
```

or:

```
=FILTER(MasterList!A2:A, REGEXMATCH(LOWER(MasterList!E2:E), "tl|aaa"))
```